# Access PPTP clients from LAN

Tags: vpn, routing, pptp

I have this type of network:
[Network schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qen3a.png)

Main router with LAN address 192.168.2.1
Also have VPN server on this router with address 172.17.0.1
The client connects from internet to my VPN server and gets address 172.17.0.2

I want to access from LAN computer (192.168.2.12) to VPN server client (172.17.0.2)

Commands output on router with VPN server:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:B4:29:59:16:FA
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29042093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27035355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6797855731 (6.3 GiB)  TX bytes:16000949999 (14.9 GiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:B4:29:59:16:FA
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67070012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55588755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:34807273144 (32.4 GiB)  TX bytes:24402031899 (22.7 GiB)
          Interrupt:5

eth2.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:B4:29:59:16:FA
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29060479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28806877 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6870793540 (6.3 GiB)  TX bytes:16464725205 (15.3 GiB)

eth2.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:B4:29:59:16:FB
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:224238221 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:386759456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:65429076277 (60.9 GiB)  TX bytes:413343501047 (384.9 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1149736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1149736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:123384114 (117.6 MiB)  TX bytes:123384114 (117.6 MiB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr: 95.188.X.X  P-t-P:213.228.116.44  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1458  Metric:1
          RX packets:19703357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15666178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:9637749052 (8.9 GiB)  TX bytes:4377398909 (4.0 GiB)

ppp10     Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  P-t-P:172.17.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:555 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:51805 (50.5 KiB)  TX bytes:32390 (31.6 KiB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:B4:29:59:16:FB
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:503175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:556296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:66198645 (63.1 MiB)  TX bytes:504468271 (481.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:6

ra1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F2:B4:29:58:16:FB
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20460 (19.9 KiB)  TX bytes:15246 (14.8 KiB)

rai0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F0:B4:29:59:16:FC
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6047558 errors:8969 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10069240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1852292971 (1.7 GiB)  TX bytes:13384955730 (12.4 GiB)
          Interrupt:4

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2973058 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1296677 errors:0 dropped:10803 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:3854771479 (3.5 GiB)  TX bytes:105164985 (100.2 MiB)
```

```
/opt/home/admin # route -e
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         krsn-bras5.sib. 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ppp0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth2.2
10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
172.17.0.2      *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp10
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2.2
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
213.228.116.44  *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
```

ppp10 is VPN server iface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and trying different rules I found a solution:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ppp10 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

After this I can access to 172.17.0.0/24 subnet of my VPN server